# getting started with org mode in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am new to computer science - so far, I have written a kinetic monte carlo simulation in Python and my background is in physics.

I am trying to learn org-mode in emacs, but it seems that I am lacking some very basic knowledge, and I don't know where to start obtaining it.

For example, I don't know exactly what this tutorial is telling me to do from the very beginning:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html

How do I "point the Emacs load path to the lisp directory in the Org-mode distribution"

It says:

"Activation
Add the following to your .emacs:"

Where is my .emacs?

I know these are very basic questions.

I understand how to write code to some extent and have written programs in visual basic and java, but I am lacking in some fundamentals of CS. What is the knowledge base I am lacking, and what courses/resources can I use to obtain it?

Comment: If you want to get started with emacs you can try to follow [Xah Lee](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs.html) tutorials.

Comment: Please don't kill me for asking this, but what does "Save it at ~/.emacs.d/init.el" mean?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html -- this is actually a first hit of the [what is .emacs](https://google.com/search?q=what%20is%20.emacs) google query.

Comment: IOW, you'll be better off following a basic Emacs tutorial. The Org tutorial seems to assume some basic Emacs knowledge that you don't currenty possess yet. I recommend starting emacs and then clicking "Help" and then clicking "Emacs Tutorial" if you run emacs in some sort of graphical environment. If you run in a a terminal, type "C-h t" (i.e. the "control" key and the "h" key together and then the "t" key separately).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The Xah Lee tutorials are nice.